# Add new column with values as one two three etc

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
eid       ename         
1          abc          
2          def         
3          ghi         
4          jkl
```

Expected Result:

```
eid      ename       newCol
1         abc         one
2         def         two
3         ghi         three
4         jkl         four
```

Comment: You must have a rule which tells what to write where. Why "two" is row #2 and not #3? Why "one" is row #1? What other values should go into this column? (In Spark you don't operate on row level, you must create a rule for the whole column)

Answer (score 0):

As spark has no native library to convert number to words we have to use some external python library to achieve the same

I have use num2words details [here](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/)

first install it using

```
pip install num2words
```

then it can be used as below

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from num2words import num2words
data=[(1,"abc"),(2,"def"),(3,"efg"),(4,"jkl")]
tdf=spark.createDataFrame(data,["eid","ename"])
spark.udf.register("num2name",lambda s :num2words(s),StringType())
tdf.withColumn("new_col",num2name(F.col("eid"))).show()

#output
+---+-----+-------+
|eid|ename|new_col|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1|  abc|    one|
|  2|  def|    two|
|  3|  efg|  three|
|  4|  jkl|   four|
+---+-----+-------+
```